# Side by side installation problems with Visual Studio 2008

Tags: visual-c++

I develop an unmanaged DLL with Visual C++ which is part of my application. I have always had various problems with linking the VC runtime library. Somehow I managed with VS 2005, but since I moved to VS 2008, the release version of my DLL no longer works on any PC other than the one with my development tools (namely VS 2008).

I link the runtime library as multi-threaded DLL (/MD). I tried the /MT option but that causes a lot of error messages. I allow isolation of the manifest file, and of course installed the VC++ 2008 runtime (although I don't think it should be needed). I also tried the dependency walker to check what is missing. On my development PC (VS 2008 SP1 installed) three files are reported missing:

MSVCR90.DLL, GPSVC.DLL, IESHIMS.DLL

But that does not stop the application (and my DLL) from running.

On all other PCs I tried to install my application on, apart from these three, a fourth file is reported as missing by dep. walker: MSVCP90.DLL.

More importantly, my own DLL is not working as well.
I know this is nothing new and I tried to read everything I could find about SxS problems but I still don't know what to do. Hopefully my description of the 'phenomenon' is good enough for someone more experienced to give me some help.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

You may need to distribute and install [Microsoft Visual C++ 2008 Redistributable](http://www.microsoft.com/download/en/details.aspx?displaylang=en&id=29), OR SP1 versionf of it.

Comment: It should not be needed but I already tried these, too. It does not work. Unfortunately, the error message displayed by Windows does not help at all. It only says that my .exe can't 'see' my own dll, even though it is in the same folder.
Is there any other tool I can use to check what seems to be missing? Dependency walker reports three files (see above) missing on my development PC with VS installed, but the application works there. On other PCs a fourth (MSVCP90.DLL) is reported missing. Is this a clue for anyone?

Comment: Ensure you have correct VC Runtime SP installed on target machine. You can install RTM and SPs on one machine too.

Comment: I tried several (both 2008 redistributable and its SP1 version). How do I know I have the right one? Thanks.

Comment: In your development machine, check which version of VS2008 is installed in Help->About. Do check the info on the LEFT side of dialog box and NOT on right side (which is .NET framework version info).

Comment: This is the info on the left: Version 9.0.30729.4462 QFE